# Accidentally deleted EVERYTHING in /usr/local

Tags: command-line, rm

I performed `sudo rm -rf newfolder`, when I was in `/usr/local/` directory. It has deleted everything inside that folder! I only wanted to delete newfolder inside that directory. How can I restore what was inside it? I don't ever know if there was anything inside it to begin with!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

It's an Ubuntu 15.10 machine

Thanks!

Comment: Even worse: "/usr/local/" is a local directory so it contains your software not something from Ubuntu. You need a backup.

Comment: Will anything happen because if this? It was not more than an hour ago i installed Ubuntu. I am not even sure if there was anything in it.

Comment: Normally, a clean install should not have anything in `/usr/local`. Well, some packages create links/folders there as a framework for locally-built packages to put their stuff in (e.g. `/usr/local/man` points to `/usr/local/share/man`).  And some 'ecosystems' like Python tooling tends to use this folder heavily (e.g. when you `pip install` something as root). Not sure how to restore the initial state of that folder as a clean install, let alone the specific state of your system at the time of removal... so it's like impossible to post an answer to this here, really.

Answer (score 3):

**Oops, did that just happen?**

We all have made an `rm` mistake once in our glorious Linux lives.. well I've. Sadly, it can not be undone. Sucks that it has happened but maybe it is time to learn what whent wrong to prevent it from happing again.

**sudo rm -rf newfolder**

```
user ~/testrm$ ls
newfolder  test  test2  testdir
user ~/testrm$ sudo rm -rf newfolder
user ~/testrm$ ls
test  test2  testdir
user ~/testrm$ sudo rm -rf newfolder
user ~/testrm$ ls
test  test2  testdir
```

Welp, clearly that did not remove everything within the directory. The question is, what did?

Possibilty is often that people do `sudo rm -rf newfolder *`, the space after newfolder is what removes everything within the directory.

**man rm**
rm - remove files or directories, the -r is needed to remove directories and their contents recursively.

-f, --force, ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt.

> I highly advice to not just use -f.

Check your history by the command `history` and you could discover what happened.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that post. "clearly that did not remove everything within the directory" - That probably means there was nothing in the /etc/local/ directory. Right? I installed Ubuntu not less that 10 minutes back and the only thing I installed is Java. I am 100% positive i did not use `sudo rm -rf newfolder *`

Comment: To be honest, I'm an Arch user and I do not have an `/etc/local/` - check the comment of Rinzwind, he is correct that it contains installed software. So yes, chances are big it was empty! "phew"

Comment: I do have an `/usr/local`, sorry - I looked at your content. I can't tell what is in in clean though.. been ages.